# Can we use Firebase as a common backend for an iOS app and Wordpress website both?

Tags: ios, swift, wordpress, firebase, web

We are creating an employer/employee platform where employer would like to use a Wordpress website while the employees will use an iOS app.

Because of our newness to iOS development, we only are proficient in using Firebase as the backend for iOS apps.

Is it possible to use the same (Firebase) backend for the iOS app, and our Wordpress website as well ?

If not, what other technology stack can we use for backend that will serve both our iOS app and the Wordpress website ?

thank you in advance:)

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple apps across multiple platforms use the backend services in a single Firebase project.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it seems there’s no way we could find to integrate **Wordpress** website with Firebase though..

Comment: by the way i read that answer before posting this question and that’s why specifically mentioned WORDPRESS website in the question title.. i think this question is wrongly duped/closed.

Comment: You essentially combined two questions: 1) Can I use the same Firebase project from a web app and a iOS app? 2) Can I use Firebase from a Wordpress site? The first question is a duplicate, and thus was closed as such. On Wordpress: if I search for https://www.google.com/search?q=use+firebase+and+wordpress, I see some interesting articles on using Firebase in a Wordpress site. If you're having specific problems with making that work, post the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and it'll be more likely that someone can help you.